# Comparing 3 integers using bash

Tags: bash

Hey so why am I getting a syntax error on my conditionals. I've checked with previous questions online on the use of quotes `""` and `[[]]` and made sure to use both. Also the `&&` symbol in the `if` statement but I can't seem to get it to work any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Please input integer number 1
read i1
echo Please input integer number 2
read i2
echo Please input integer number 3
read i3
if [[ "$i1" >= "$i2" ]] && [[ "$i1" >= "$i3" ]];then
    echo $i1
elif [[ "$i2" >= "$i1" ]] && [[ "$i2" >= "$i3" ]];then
    echo $i2
else
    echo $i3
fi
```

Comment: You can use `-ge` for greater than or equal to in `[[  ]]` or you can force an arithmetic comparison by using `(( ))` instead of the `[[ ]]` like `(( $i1 >= $i2 ))`.  Note that you have missed an `fi` in your code

Comment: oh sorry that was supposed to be an elif but will try out

Comment: Edited.  In the future, please feel free to update your question yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `-ge` instead of `>=`

Try `man test` for more information

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Please input integer number 1
read i1
echo Please input integer number 2
read i2
echo Please input integer number 3
read i3
if [[ "$i1" -ge "$i2" ]] && [[ "$i1" -ge "$i3" ]];then
    echo $i1
elif [[ "$i2" -ge "$i1" ]] && [[ "$i2" -ge "$i3" ]];then
    echo $i2
else
    echo $i3
fi
```